# REALLY simple PIVOT example MS SQL 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014

All the examples I can find for pivot tables involve aggregates and seem too complicated to achieve what I'm trying to do, which seems like it ought to be really simple: take an existing table with a fixed number of rows and present the data in column instead of row format.

Here's some mythical data:

```
DECLARE @HSData TABLE (

      School            NVARCHAR(20)
    , Sophomores        INTEGER
    , Juniors           INTEGER
    , Seniors           INTEGER
    , Total             INTEGER
    )

INSERT INTO @HSData VALUES
      ('Armstrong HS',397,337,318,0)
    , ('Buchanan HS',383,325,308,0)
    , ('Carlsbad HS',338,321,285,0)

UPDATE @HSData
    SET Total = Sophomores + Juniors + Seniors

 SELECT * FROM @HSData
```

Results are as follows:

[image]

What I want is data that looks like this:

[image]

I can achieve this by manually inserting the data into variables using this code:

```
DECLARE 
          @AName            NVARCHAR(20)
        , @BName            NVARCHAR(20)
        , @CName            NVARCHAR(20)
        , @A10              INTEGER
        , @A11              INTEGER
        , @A12              INTEGER
        , @B10              INTEGER
        , @B11              INTEGER
        , @B12              INTEGER
        , @C10              INTEGER
        , @C11              INTEGER
        , @C12              INTEGER

SET @AName = (SELECT School FROM (SELECT School, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY School) RN FROM @HSData) SR WHERE RN = 1)
SET @BName = (SELECT School FROM (SELECT School, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY School) RN FROM @HSData) SR WHERE RN = 2)
SET @CName = (SELECT School FROM (SELECT School, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY School) RN FROM @HSData) SR WHERE RN = 3)
SET @A10  = (SELECT Sophomores FROM @HSData WHERE School = @AName)
SET @B10  = (SELECT Sophomores FROM @HSData WHERE School = @BName)
SET @C10  = (SELECT Sophomores FROM @HSData WHERE School = @CName)
SET @A11  = (SELECT Juniors    FROM @HSData WHERE School = @AName)
SET @B11  = (SELECT Juniors    FROM @HSData WHERE School = @BName)
SET @C11  = (SELECT Juniors    FROM @HSData WHERE School = @CName)
SET @A12  = (SELECT Seniors    FROM @HSData WHERE School = @AName)
SET @B12  = (SELECT Seniors    FROM @HSData WHERE School = @BName)
SET @C12  = (SELECT Seniors    FROM @HSData WHERE School = @CName)

    DECLARE @HSData2 TABLE (

          Class                 NVARCHAR(20)
        , "Armstrong HS"        INTEGER
        , "Buchanan HS"         INTEGER
        , "Carlsbad HS"         INTEGER
        )

INSERT INTO @HSData2 VALUES
          ('Sophomores',@A10,@B10,@C10)
        , ('Juniors',   @A11,@B11,@C11)
        , ('Seniors',   @A12,@B12,@C12)
        , ('Total',     @A10+@A11+@A12,@B10+@B11+@B12,@C10+@C11+@C12)

SELECT * FROM @HSData2
```

But it seems like there ought to be a better way.

Ideally, I can get this all into an SSRS report and then not worry about it. But it still struck me as a bit odd that I couldn't find any simpler code for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpivot the data first then pivot.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    @HSData
UNPIVOT (
    Students 
    FOR Class IN (Sophomores, Juniors, Seniors, Total)
) up
PIVOT (
    SUM(Students)
    FOR School IN ([Armstrong HS], [Buchanan HS], [Carlsbad HS])
) p 
ORDER BY CASE Class WHEN 'Sophomores' THEN 1
                    WHEN 'Juniors' THEN 2
                    WHEN 'Seniors' THEN 3
                    WHEN 'Total' THEN 4 END
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be much easier to **UNPIVOT** the data and let the **MATRIX** in SSRS worry about putting it back together like you want.

```
SELECT U.SCHOOL, U.CLASS, U.TOTALS
FROM TABLE1 S
UNPIVOT
(
  TOTALS
  FOR CLASS IN (SOPHMORES, JUNIORS, SENIORS)
) U;
```

For the Matrix, have a **Row Group** by **Class** and the **Column Group** by **School**.

You could also make another matrix that has a **Row Group** by **School** and **Column Group** by **Class** using the same data.